# DetailsList component is not taking into account selection property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I have created the following sample application to try and simplify as much as possible an issue I am having as part of a larger application I am working on.
The issue has to do with the selection property of the DetailsList component in office-ui-fabric-react.

I have included the main components of the sample application below to try and illustrate my issue.

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { ClickedItemsList } from './ClickedItemsList';
import { GenerateItemButton } from './GenerateItemButton';
import { ItemSelectionStore } from './ItemSelectionStore';

class App extends React.Component {

  public itemSelectionStore: ItemSelectionStore = new ItemSelectionStore();

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <GenerateItemButton store={this.itemSelectionStore} />
          <ClickedItemsList store={this.itemSelectionStore} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ItemSelectionStore.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { ClickedItemsList } from './ClickedItemsList';
import { GenerateItemButton } from './GenerateItemButton';
import { ItemSelectionStore } from './ItemSelectionStore';

class App extends React.Component {

  public itemSelectionStore: ItemSelectionStore = new ItemSelectionStore();

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <GenerateItemButton store={this.itemSelectionStore} />
          <ClickedItemsList store={this.itemSelectionStore} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

GenerateItemButton.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { ItemSelectionStore } from './ItemSelectionStore';

export interface IGenerateItemButtonProps {
    store: ItemSelectionStore
}

export class GenerateItemButton extends React.Component<IGenerateItemButtonProps> {

    public render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        )
    }

    private handleClick = () => 
        this.props.store.onAddItemButtonClicked();
}
```

ClickedItemList

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import {CheckboxVisibility, DetailsList, IColumn, IObjectWithKey, Selection, SelectionMode } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList';
import * as React from 'react';
import { ItemSelectionStore } from './ItemSelectionStore';

export interface IClickedItemsListProps {
    store: ItemSelectionStore
}

@observer
export class ClickedItemsList extends React.Component<IClickedItemsListProps> {

    private columns: IColumn[] = [{ key: 'key', name: 'Extracted key', fieldName: 'key', minWidth: 150 }];

    public render() {
        const { store } = this.props;
        const selectedItems = store.selectedItems;

        // creating items to display
        const itemsToDisplay: IObjectWithKey[] = [];
        selectedItems.forEach(k => itemsToDisplay.push({'key': k}));

        // creating selection
        const selection = new Selection();
        selection.setItems(itemsToDisplay);
        selection.setAllSelected(true);

        return (
            <DetailsList
                items={itemsToDisplay}
                selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
                columns={this.columns}
                checkboxVisibility={CheckboxVisibility.always}
                selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
                selection={selection}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

When a user clicks on the button a random string is added to a list of items which are dynamically displayed by the ClickedItemsList component.

The items appear as they should on every click but I am having trouble with the selection property.
I want all items added to the list to also be in a selected state but my sample application fails to do so and all items simply appear in a non selected state.

Thoughts ?